# event.preventDefault() not working on second of two input boxes

Tags: jquery, html, input

/I have two input boxes, each in a separate form element set, in the html:

```
<input id="RecommendationDaysInputTextBox" class="NumberOfDaysInputTextBox" name="RecommendationDaysInputTextBox" type="text" value="90" />
<input id="ReviewDaysInputTextBox" class="NumberOfDaysInputTextBox" name="ReviewDaysInputTextBox" type="text" value="360" />
```

I want to stop default propogation upon the user hitting the enter key after entering data (which I correct with "change" and "keyup").

I am using this:

```
$(".NumberOfDaysInputTextBox").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        /* e.stopPropagation(); */
        $(this).trigger("change");
    }
});​
```

It is working on the first box but not the second.  Hitting enter on the second causes post and refresh (all browsers).  This occurs regardless of the order in which I enter data into a box and hit enter.

Does anyone have an explanation as to what I am doing wrong and how to do it correctly?

Comment: Everything looks ok. Try `alert($(".NumberOfDaysInputTextBox").length)` just before event subscription.

Comment: Posting the problem at http://jsfiddle.net will make it more likely that others will help you

Comment: How about `$('.myForm.').submit(function(e){e.preventDefault});`.  You can still keep your `keyup` event listener, but need not worry about keycodes and all that.

Comment: This suggestion worked great -- no codes.  It may be the preferred answer.  I will eventually need to submit the form and will have to work that out in this function, perhaps with an embedded ".submit()" statement following the e.preventDefault() statement.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, I guess, is that the submit is triggered immediately on keydown. If you instead set the function to execute on keydown...

```
$(".NumberOfDaysInputTextBox").keydown(function(e)
{
    if (e.which == 13)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).trigger("change");
    }
});​
```

... the problem seems to get solved.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jthGY/

Comment: Thank you.  Putting the e.preventDefault(), and only that, in keydown, then having my "change" trigger in keyup, makes it perfect.  I will also try the ".submit" technique mentioned in the comment to the original question.  Looks like a winner, no codes.

Comment: No problem. Thanks Gromer for the link, I tried but, lacking time, failed to find it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use keyup, since it has already triggered the default action by that point.  Reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html.  Look into using keydown.